Media Projection Service with WebRTC does not show playing video
I use the Media Projection Service to get the full screen on my device
private fun startScreenCapture(){
    val mediaProjectionManager = getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as MediaProjectionManager
    ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(this, mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), 1, null)
}

and send that via WebRTC to a local webpage that displays the device's screen.
The device's screen displays fine on the local webpage but I noticed that if a video is playing in an android VideoView
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

the video does not get captured. All other UI elements on the screen are visible just not what is playing in the video view. I dont know if this is a limitation of the Media Projection Service or WebRTC or maybe I need to do something extra to have the video show?

I would start by trying something else that uses the media projection APIs (e.g., to record a screencast, such as this open source app) and seeing if it records the VideoView. If it does, you know the problem is downstream from that. If it does not, then the media projection APIs are not liking your VideoView, either in general or due to some sort of copyright flag.

@CommonsWare - open source app is not available anymore. Also does this screen share work when Android app is having webview and then that webview in turn shows youtube video or any other video in inframe?
